# Mongoose array type incorrectly validating non-arrays

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm using Mongoose 4.8.0 and I have the following partial schema:

```
const UserSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    completed: [{
        type: String,
        enum: ['ONBOARDING', 'INTRO_MODAL', 'SAVED_FAVORITES']
    }]
});
const User = mongoose.model('Users', UserSchema);
```

If I run the following code:

```
User.findOneAndUpdate(
    { _id: userId },
    { $set: { completed: ['foo'] } },
    { runValidators: true },
    callback
);
```

I get a validation error like I expect since `'foo'` is not one of the `enum` provided.

But when I run the following code:

```
User.findOneAndUpdate(
    { _id: userId },
    { $set: { completed: false } },
    { runValidators: true },
    callback
);
```

The validation for the array is bypassed and I end up with a `User` document with `completed: false`. This also works for setting `completed` to anything other than an array.

How do I ensure that `completed` can only be an array of strings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case anyone else comes across this same issue, I found that upgrading to Mongoose 4.11.x fixed this. It must have been a bug.